# How instantaneous stabilizer groups look like in honeycomb code

Tags: error-correction

In the paper ["Dynamically Generated Logical Qubits" By Hastings and Haah](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2021-10-19-564/), they show how the stabilizers of the state change when they project the state using the different types of edge measurements.

According to this paper, given a state which is stabilized by the stabilizer group $S$ and projecting it using operator $P$, the stabilizer group would change according to $P$ and $S$:

- if $P \in S$ then this was a simple stabilizer measurement and nothing will change
- if $P \notin S$ but $P$ commute with every element in $S$ then $P$ will be added to the stabilizer group
- if $P \notin S$ but anti-commute with some element in $S$, it will replace it as the stabilizer.

They say that after the second round of measurements, measuring the type 1 edges, the state should be stabilized by type 1 edges and type 2 hexagons.

I do not understand how the type 2 hexagon is also a stabilizer.

[image: type2hexagon]

At the beginning of the round the state is stabilized by all of the 0 edges.

After doing the first type 1 edge measurement, the edge touches two type 0 edges. It anti-commutes with each of them, so to my understanding, it will replace it as a stabilizer, and the state will be stabilized only by a single type 0 edge and a single type 1 edge.

The same goes for the other two type 1 edges, and I do not see why the entire hexagon is also a stabilizer.

If all of the type 2 edges are measured at once, and the operator $P$ is a multiplication of them, then $P$ will commute with the type 0 edges, since each type 0 edge anti-commutes with two type 1 edges. Is that the case?

If so, then doesn't it mean that the type 0 edges are still stabilizers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume we start with no stabilizers and measure XX on the three type 0 edges in your drawing. The qubits on the vertices are then in an eigenstate of (are stabilized by) the following operators:
\begin{equation}
\{X_1 X_2, X_3 X_4, X_5 X_6\}
\end{equation}
Here I've labeled the qubits on the vertices from one to six. We can multiply these three stabilizers to find a weight six stabilizer: $$S_2 = X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4 X_5 X_6$$. This is the stabilizer on the hexagon.

Now if we measure ZZ (or YY) on the three type 1 edges, $S_2$ is still a stabilizer, because it commutes with each of the three measured operators ($Z_2Z_3, Z_4Z_5, Z_6Z_1$).

The qubits aren't stabilized by type 0 edges anymore because they don't commute with the measured operators. For example, $X_1 X_2$ and $Z_2 Z_3$ don't commute.